# Windows 7 Parental Controls *With* Domain Accounts

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls, windows-domain

There are many how-tos on how to enable Windows 7 Parental Controls while a computer is joined to a domain.  However, what I would like is a 'hack' to enable parental controls on a ***domain account***.  I don't care if the settings would have to be applied on each computer (my son only is able to login to his own machine, anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft recently released parental controls that van be managed through a Live account.  This parental control software can be used to filter web access and other items.  it cannot use all the features such as login times, etc., but those are managed through AD anyway.

http://fss.live.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a "hack" but i found a workaround that works on my domain.
I have noticed that in the parental control tool, it is only possible to add standard local user accounts or administrator accounts (local or domain).

So on my son's computer (Win 7 Ultimate joined to the domain), I have added his domain user account in the local administrator group.
When this is done, it is possible to link this account with the parental control.

Then, I removed his domain account from the local administrator group, and it still works !
I can manage the web filtering on the microsoft web site without any problem.

The only option that does not work is the time restriction, but this can be easily done in the active directory with logon hours options.

I would appreciate if somebody can test this workaround to check if it works on other domain configuration than mine.

Comment: Hmm, not able to reproduce.  I tried adding his account to the computer admin group, doing a gpupdate /force, having him log in, etc.  Still no dice.